# eclipse mysql connectivity

Tags: mysql, eclipse, jdbc, connection, classnotfoundexception

I am working on a project where we need to access tables from mysql database. But, I keep getting the following exception in eclipse.

```
java.lang.classnotfoundexception com.mysql.jdbc.driver
```

I have downloaded the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.23` and tried placing the jar file at lib file of the project and since it didnt work I placed it in Apache's lib..But again got the same problem..I have also tried setting the environment class path variable to point to the `jar file`..but it still didn't work..

I am using eclipse juno and MySQL Server 5.0 with apache tomcat 7.0

please help!

Answer (score 1):

try this

right click on the project

```
-->buildpath
 -->configure build path
-->add external jar files
and then select your jar file
```

you need to add to the build path of the project.

Comment: please mark it as answer if you got the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating JPA project then you have to add the .jar files.

Right click on project->buildpath->configure build path.
In that click the "Libraries" on the top.
Now click the Add External Jars and browse the jar u downloaded and add.

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project select Propertys then select Java Build Path and add your file as external JAR